# Is there a way to include a 95% margin of error to tbl_summary?

Tags: confidence-interval, gtsummary

I have been asked to create a margin of error table for some data. Does anyone know how I can do this? I'm a big fan of gtsummary. It's so easy to use, so I was hoping that I could use this package.

It's easy to add a 95% confidence interval to tbl_summary (see below) but I just can't work out how to make this a margin of error instead.

I think it requires add_stat and a function but I still haven't got my head around how to do it.

Appreciate your help

```
mtcars %>%  
  select(mpg, cyl) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = cyl) %>% 
  add_ci()
```

Comment: You can add any statistic(s) you like to a gtsummary table with `add_stat()`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I've been trying to figure out how to write the function for it to use with add_stat, but can't get it to work. Appreciate your help.